# SonataMediaBundle You have requested a non-existent parameter "doctrine.connections" error

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin

I have setup a SonataAdminBundle on my Symfony 2.1.2 project and it works correctly. Now I´m trying to setup a SonataMediaBundle but I get this error:

```
==> php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataMediaBundle



  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]  
  You have requested a non-existent parameter "doctrine.connections".
```

I copied the config parameters to config.yml as indicates the documentation. You can see it there: http://pastebin.com/wys11net

Any help or clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the Connections node inside the Doctrine > DBAL's node, aswell the specification of a default connection (among multiple connections, if that would be the case).
An example of the *right* template would be like

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
```

Comment: One question @Thomas, after this change, I´m not abble to connect to my database, I´m getting this error:SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). Do you know why?

Comment: Make sure you have the right username/password combination for your localhost at the parameters.ini file

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem as well, and found that the "connections" node is not actually required in the config (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration ... you only need the connections node when you have multiple connections).

In my case, it was that I had the SonataCacheBundle in the AppKernel.php file before Doctrine. Doctrine sets the "doctrine.connections" parameter when Doctrine initializes, so if you try to access it in SonataCacheBundle before Doctrine has initialized then "doctrine.connections" is not in the container yet.

Reordering the entries in AppKernel.php fixed the issue for me.